# Load a web app inside a WebView on the Oculus Quest 2 VR headset

Tags: java, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I have a web app that I am trying to wrap inside an SDK. I already have the app wrapped in the [official APK wrapper](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/web/pwa-packaging/), which just loads the web app remotely.

I'm now building my own APK wrapper using a WebView. The app works fine, but when I add the required AndroidManifest.xml settings of `<category android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" />`, the app loads with a black screen and three animating dots. [This is the only relevant resource](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Get-Help/Black-screen-with-3-dots-FIX-maybe/m-p/988297/highlight/true#M152106) on the community forum, but isn't helpful as the HTML I'm loading is just `<h1>Test</h1>` from a local HTML file in the assets folder.

Does anyone know if this is a bug on Oculus Quest 2 devices or something I'm doing wrong?

Relevant code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.enijar.test"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking" android:required="true"
        android:version="1" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!-- This is the line that causes the infinite loading screen -->
                <category android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.enijar.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    private static class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**assets/index.html**

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```